# Netty: ClientBootstrap connect retries

Tags: java, netty

I need to connect to a server, which I know will be listening on a port. Although It could take some time to get operational. Is it possible to get ClientBootstrap to try to connect for a given number of tries or until a timeout is reached?

At the moment, if the connection is refused, I get an exception, but it should try to connect in background, for example by respecting the "connectTimeoutMillis" bootstrap option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need todo it by hand, but thats not hard..

You could do something like this:

```
final ClientBootstrap bs = new ClientBootstrap(...);
final InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress("remoteip", 110);
final int maxretries = 5;
final AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();
bs.connect(address).addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {

    public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
        if (!future.isSuccess()) {
            if (count.incrementAndGet() > maxretries) {
                // fails to connect even after maxretries do something
            } else {
                // retry
                bs.connect(address).addListener(this);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this code snippet and it seems to create lots of threads. If you put Thread.sleep(10*1000) and a println just before you try to reconnect using bootstrap, you can see that more then one threads are printing that message and all of them are trying to connect to server as well. My code is almost same except Thread.sleep() before i try to reconnect, and when it fails toconnect few times, I can see that more then one threads are created and all of them are trying to connect.

Here's my code http://pastebin.com/9mzgVkRd