# Netty ProxyHandler - Retry Connect with Alternate Host

Tags: netty

I'm trying to wrap my head around what would be the best way to retry the `ProxyHandler.connect()` with an alternate hostname if the connection fails for the first host.

My initial thought was to use an `exceptionCaught()` and listen for the cause `ProxyConnectException` but I then noticed that `ProxyHandler.connect()` is expecting a promise. I don't believe I have access to the original promise from within my `exceptionCaught()` and my fear is that constructing a new one at this point will break any further notifying down the pipeline.

Are my fears unfounded and am I OK to just call `ProxyHandler.connect()` with a new promise? Should I just reconstruct my own ProxyHandler so I can handle an alternate host directly in the `connect()`?

Comment: Could you just attach a ChannelFutureListener to the connect promise and then retry if the future fails ?

Comment: @NormanMaurer The connect promise you're talking about would be the one returned from Bootstrap.connect() correct? I guess with that ChannelFutureListener I could just remove the ProxyHandler that failed and add a new one with the alternate host and fire Bootstrap.connect() again. I'll investigate this and report back.

Comment: Yes that's what I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggestion made by @NormanMaurer to attach a ChannelFutureListener worked in my case. My theory of reworking the channel's pipeline wasn't appropriate though. I instead made my channel initializer aware of the alternate host and whether it needed to build the ProxyHandler using it. I believe I was overcomplicating everything when in reality I basically needed to do what @NormanMaurer had suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873237/netty-clientbootstrap-connect-retries) for connection retries.